# Howto use MQTTNET with WSS

Tags: mqtt, wss, kestrel

i build an app in net7 to use the mqttserver from MQTTNET.
The connection over WS and TCP (port 1883) workes, but the Secure WSS not.
I have generate a selfSigned certificate with opensssl.
When this workes i want to generate and import the certificate with letsencrypt if this is possible?

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseKestrel(option =>
                {
                    option.ListenAnyIP(1883, l => l.UseMqtt());
                    option.ListenAnyIP(5001, listenOptions =>
                    {
                        var path = 
                        Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                        var certPath = Path.Combine(path, "certificate.pfx");
                        var cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, "12345");

                        listenOptions.UseHttps(cert);
                    });
                    option.ListenAnyIP(5005); // default HTTP Port
                });
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Startup.cs

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, 
        MqttServerController mqttController)
     {
     if (env.IsDevelopment())
     {
         app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
     }

     app.UseRouting();

     app.UseEndpoints(
         endpoints =>
         {
             endpoints.MapConnectionHandler<MqttConnectionHandler>(
             "/mqtt",
                 httpConnectionDispatcherOptions => 
                     httpConnectionDispatcherOptions.WebSockets.SubProtocolSelector =
                     protocolList => protocolList.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty);
         });

     app.UseMqttServer(
         server =>
         {
             server.ValidatingConnectionAsync += mqttController.ValidateConnection;
             server.ClientConnectedAsync += mqttController.OnClientConnected;
             server.InterceptingPublishAsync += 
                  mqttController.InterceptApplicationMessagePublishAsync;
         });
      }

       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {

           services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

           services.AddSingleton<DataContext>();
           services.AddSingleton<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
           services.AddSingleton<IUserService, UserService>();
           services.AddSingleton<IDeviceRepository, DeviceRepository>();
           services.AddSingleton<IDeviceService, DeviceService>();

           services.AddHostedMqttServer(
                optionsBuilder =>
                {
                    optionsBuilder.WithoutDefaultEndpoint();
                });

           services.AddMqttConnectionHandler();
           services.AddMqttWebSocketServerAdapter();
           services.AddConnections();

           services.AddSingleton<MqttServerController>();
       }
```

I have written an Angular APP with the ngx-mqtt (javascsript lib)
Here is bowsers output
[image]

What i missing or doing wrong in my implementation?
Thanks
Markus

Comment: What is the actual question here? Is it about the Angular app or the MQTTNET app? The Web app is unlikely to work unless you also import and trust the certificate in the browser as it will **NOT** ask you to accept the unknown cert like a webpage. If the problem is with the MQTTNET app include the errors from that app, not the browser.

Comment: @hardillb, sorry i have forgot to write that i imported the certificate in my browser... i dont know wheres the problem, i think on the net application, the question is have i missed somithing in my application? how to debug it?

Comment: Does the cert have the right CN/SAN entries? What does wireshark show? What errors do the broker logs show?